# Битрикс - как сделать свойства товара множественным?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

В свойстве товара поставил галочку множественное. В итоге в самой  карточке товар, где выводится это свойство пишет Array. 1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом 20.0.0.
Как ему вывести этот список на странице в виде раскрывающегося списка у товара?

Comment: в шаблоне обработать через forEach

Comment: Как узнать какое имя массива будет?

Comment: на память не помню. Но у тебя сейчас пытается вывести но натыкается на массив

Comment: Я понимаю да. Не могу еще врубиться какой именно шаблон-файл у него используется для карточки товара. Вроде как прямо с карточки товара можно в редактировании вызвать, но не пойму что именно редактировать. Есть каталог и есть элемент каталога детально.

Comment: detail.php  Но бывают нюансы

Comment: Нашел. Он по символьному коду свойства выводится , типа так $arResult["PROPERTIES"]["DIAM"]["VALUE"] .  Ох какое гавно все таки этот битрикс...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в файле шаблона карточки товара в блоке выводе свойств добавить

```
if(is_array($property["VALUE"])&& !empty($property["VALUE"])){
    echo implode(", ", $property["VALUE"]);
}elseif($property["VALUE"]!=""){
    echo $property["VALUE"];
}
```